# How to get content between the search patterns

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, sh

I have some text in this format.

```
echo "Hi"
line A 
line B
echo "hello"
line C
echo "him"
line D
echo "hind legs"
```

When I grep for "hi"  I will get

```
echo "Hi"
echo "him"
echo "hind legs"
```

My requirement is to get all the lines in between the search lines.
Required Output:

Data 1:

```
echo "Hi"
line A 
line B
echo "hello"
line C
echo "him"
```

Data2:

```
echo "him"
line D
echo "hind legs"
```

Kindly help.

Comment: did you want the output in two separate files?

Comment: It is fine to have it in two separate files or in different variables also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk will split the input into several files `data1.txt`, `data2.txt` and so forth:

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ "hi" { if(fname) { print > fname; close(fname) } ++n; fname = "data" n ".txt" } { print > fname }' filename
```

It works as follows:

```
tolower($0) ~ "hi" {         # If a line matches the search pattern
                             # case-insensitively,
  if(fname) {                # if there is a current file (i.e., if this is
                             # not the first delimiter line),
    print > fname            # print it to the current file
    close(fname)             # then close that file
  }
  ++n                        # increase counter
  fname = "data" n ".txt"    # build new file name
}
{
  print > fname              # print lines to that current file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -ne '/echo "Hi"/,/echo "him"/p' file > data1
sed -ne '/echo "him"/,/echo "hind legs"/p' file > data2
```

Comment: My search pattern is only "hi"

I donot have multiple search patterns.